# CUDA constant memory symbols

Tags: cuda, gpu-constant-memory

I am using CUDA 5.0 and I have modules which are compiled separately.
I would like to access the same value in the constant memory from all modules.
The problem is the following, when I define the symbol in each
module the linker claims that the symbol has been redefined.
Is there a workaround or a solution for this problem?
Thank you for helping.

Comment: Are you using the runtime API? When you say "modules", are you talking about driver API modules or do you really just mean separately compiled object files using the runtime API?

Comment: Perhaps I'm wrong, but `constant memory` is defined implicitly `static`. I would then be surprised that the compiler says that the symbol is redefined, if the "modules" are separately compiled object files. Are you declaring the `constant memory` in header files?

Comment: @JackOLantern: If this is separate compilation mode, then it makes sense. The linker will detect the duplicate symbol definitions. `extern` is supported for constant symbols in separate compilation mode.

Comment: @talonmies I think your conjecture of separate compilation mode combined with the lack of proper use of `extern` is very likely correct.  If you would post an answer along those lines I would upvote it.

Comment: @talonmies defining it as extern is working, thank you. The interesting things is that, in debug mode the values are shown as not set (???), but I get correct results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In CUDA separate compilation mode, there is a true linker, and every symbol which is linked into the final device binary payload much be uniquely defined. This means __constant__ memory symbols must be only be defined in one place in all the code which is linked together.

The solution is probably to declare the symbol as `extern` at every translation unit scope except one, which contains the definition of the symbol. Note that this is the only case where it is valid to use extern with __constant__ symbols, otherwise they are implicitly static. There is a general discussion of the separate compilation model which describes this scenario buried in the documentation (both the programming guide and nvcc manual IIRC).