# CUDA COnstant memory use

Tags: c, cuda, gpu-constant-memory

I have a cuda project containing the following files

Header File:

```
 Declarations.h
```

Main File:

```
 main.cpp:
    #include "Declarations.h"
```

And Kernel File:

```
Kernel.cu:
    #include "Declarations.h"
```

In `main.cpp`, I have `float K1[3*3]` which I want to copy to GPU constant memory.
To do so, I declared `__constant__ float K1_d[3*3];`in `Declarations.h` and In `main.cpp` I did

`checkCudaErrors( cudaMemcpyToSymbol(&K1_d, &K1, 9*sizeof(float)) );`

When running the code I got the following error: `CUDA error at c:\users\xxx\test.cpp:241 code=13(cudaErrorInvalidSymbol) "cudaMemcpyToSymbol(&K1, &K1_inv, 9*sizeof(float))"`

I tried to copy one variable, for example, I declared in the header file

```
__constant__ float N;
```

And did:`checkCudaErrors( cudaMemcpyToSymbol(&N, &K1_inv[0], sizeof(float)) );`

I got the same error message of the macro chechCudaErrors.

How to transer variables to constant memory in CUDA?`

Comment: There are many questions like this and two options.  The duplicate linked answer suggests the simplest option - modify your code so that the `__constant__` declaration and the `cudaMemcpyToSymbol` usage are in the same file (compilation/translation unit).  You can also work with separate compilation and linking and use of `extern` to avoid this (such as discussed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18213988/cuda-constant-memory-symbols) ).  You will find other questions and answers about that if you search here on SO.